# Write System Call

Tags: c

I am writing this program in LINUX

```
#include <fcntl.h>
int main()
{

    int rd,id;
    char buff[10]={0};

    id = open("p_child.c",O_RDONLY|O_APPEND|O_WRONLY);
    if(id>1)
    {
        printf("I am file descriptor %d \n",id);

        rd = read(id,buff,8);
        printf("I am Reading file %s",buff);

        write(1,"New\n",4);
        printf("\nI am Writing file %s \n",buff);

    }
}
```

Its output is like printing 'New' before READ System Call.
Why is this Happening?? As Write System call is used after "printf" of Read System call.

Comment: `printf` buffers its output. Try adding `fflush(stdout);` after the second `printf` call.

Comment: or,  printf("I am Reading file %s\n",buff);

Comment: You are using an illegal `flags` parameter to `open()`. You *cannot* use `O_RDONLY | O_WRONLY` instead of `O_RDWR`. Read the manpage.

Answer (score 4):

That is because the output is buffered until you write out a line break.

Answer (score 1):

Update this line it will work

```
printf("I am Reading file %s \n",buff);
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add "\n" in printf before write system call.

```
rd = read(id,buff,8);
printf("I am Reading file %s\n",buff);
write(1,"New\n",4);
```